# Dynamic TextBlocks

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a windows phone app and I would like to implement a "tap text to expand" feature.

I have a series of `TextBlocks` that currently look much like this repeated multiple times:

```
<TextBlock 
    Name="description" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Margin="12,40,0,0" Width="444"
    TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
```

[Note the last two: `TextWrapping="NoWrap"` `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` and the lack of `Height` being set.]

This shows one line, and when the line is longer than the screen it ends in ellipsis, which is perfect. Currently, when the user taps the `TextBlock` I turn `TextWrapping` to `Wrap`. This allows the text to take as many lines as it needs (the functionality I want).

The problem is that when I turn `TextWrapping` to `Wrap` it expands into the `TextBlock` below it (remember, I have a bunch of these packed next to each other). Also, to get it to expand fully I never initially set `Height`, so if I try to access it later I get `NaN` (and `ActualHeight` never changes from 26.6, no matter how many lines it expands to be)

I'm looking for a way to dynamically push the `TextBlocks` below it down the amount necessary to display the text in its entirety, but I don't know the "correct" way to go about it. (on a similar note: hardcoding `Margin` is unideal, especially for dynamicly expanding text, is there a "`RelativeLayout`" (or something similar) that I've been unable to find? )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried placing your TextBlocks in a StackPanel?  This should prevent the TextBlock objects from overlapping and you can set their individual margin values to ensure the spacing you want.